# In git, how do I remove a commit from one branch and apply it to a different branch?

Tags: git, branch

I have two branches off of master, each one for a different feature, and then I have a synthesis branch that combines the two.  I committed something to the synthesis branch, but now I see I would have rather applied that change to one of the branches particular to that feature.  Is there a way to do this unapply/apply somewhere else maneuver with git?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Cherry-pick commit to target branch and reset source branch.  Assuming, you want to move the latest commit from `source` branch to `target`, do:

```
git checkout target
git cherry-pick source
git checkout source
git reset --hard source^
```

If the commit wasn't the last, you will have to use `git rebase -i` instead of the last command and choose specific commit name for your `cherry-pick`.

Comment: Note that reset / rebase both do **history rewriting**, so they should not be used if the history was published - then you would have to use git-revert instead.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, when I do something like this, I will:

1. Create a reverse patch file using git diff (e.g. `git diff HEAD^ HEAD`)
2. Apply this reverse patch to the branch I want to remove the change from.
3. Check out the branch I DO want the change on
4. Use `git cherry-pick`to apply the applicable commit

I believe there is an easier way, but I prefer this since I use (and remember) the diff/cherry-pick commands better