# How to move git commits from master to a different existing branch

Tags: git, branch

I checked in a few commits to `master` that should have been checked into `develop`. What git commands do I used to remove those commits from the master branch and include in the develop branch?

Comment: Have you looked at this answer? - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1773731/in-git-how-do-i-remove-a-commit-from-one-branch-and-apply-it-to-a-different-bra?rq=1

Comment: look at this: [move-recent-commit-to-a-new-branch][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1628563/move-recent-commit-to-a-new-branch

Comment: since there's a "this question may already have an answer here" block at the top, just want to point out my question is not about moving to a _new_ branch, it's about moving to a different _existing_ branch

Comment: @gitq: See Dan Hoerst's question for a solution. It's called cherry picking and works with existing branches.

Answer (score 61):

If I'm not mistaken, you had two synchronized branches,
`master` and `dev`, and simply forgot to switch the branch,
before your commits.

If that is the case, we have:

```
----------------
git log in dev

xxx
yyy
...
----------------
```

and:

```
----------------
git log in master

ccc
bbb
aaa
        <---- here you forgot to switch branch
xxx
yyy
...
----------------
```

The solution is:

First, make sure, that:

```
git status -s
```

returns empty results.

Next, get all your new commits from `master` to `dev` with:

```
git checkout dev
git merge master
```

Now return to you `master`:

```
git checkout master
```

Remove unnecessary commits:

```
git reset --hard HEAD~3
```

The number `~3` is the number of commits you want to remove.

Remember: `git status -s` have to return empty results.
Otherwise, `git reset --hard` can cause data loss.

Answer (score 19):

You can `cherry-pick` your commits over to the `develop` and afterwards interactively `rebase` your `master` branch:

1. `git checkout develop`
2. `git cherry-pick aabbcc`
3. `git cherry-pick ddeeff`
4. ....
5. `git checkout master`
6. `git rebase 123456 -i`

where `123456` is a commit before you made a mistake. This will open an editor that shows every commit that will be affected by the rebase. Delete the lines that correspond to the commits you want to discard and quit the editor.

Comment: Best answer, thank you

Answer (score 9):

For coping into another branch you can use cherry picking:

```
git cherry-pick <commit>
```

Deleting is not that easy. You can use rebase and squash or edit the commit:

```
git rebase -i <commit>~1
```

But I am not sure when chosing edit during rebase if you can edit the files also rather than the commit message only.

Comment: `edit` during an interactive rebase lets you edit commit-message and files, `reword` only lets you modify the commit-message.

Comment: After this, my head is detached at this commit. How should I make these changes to reflect on the remote branch?

Answer (score 1):

There are usually several ways to do the same thing in git one possible way:

```
git checkout develop
git cherry-pick XXX // XXX being the sha1 of the commit you want to grab
git checkout master
git rebase --interactive HEAD~IDX // IDX being the position of the last "good" commit compared to HEAD
```

The last command will display all review from HEAD to the last good commit and all you have to do is deleted the line of the commit to moved to branch develop