# Changing checked out branch

Tags: git, git-branch

Imagine the scenario:

You are in `develop` branch currently.
You created new branch. Lets say `A`
You made some commits.

But then you realized this is a hotfix and it should be based on `master` branch. And `develop` has some changes that shouldn't be in the `master` branch, yet. (gitflow)

So whats the easiest way to carry of all the changes to a new branch based on `master`?

This happened to me today. And my (stupid) solution was:

- Delete `A`
- Memorize all the changes you have made.
- Checkout to `master`.
- Create new branch. `B`
- Apply your changes to this new branch.

There has to be better way! :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In git, how do I remove a commit from one branch and apply it to a different branch?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1773731/in-git-how-do-i-remove-a-commit-from-one-branch-and-apply-it-to-a-different-bra)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So whats the easiest way to carry of all the changes to a new branch based on master?

That's what rebase does:

```
git rebase --onto master development A
```

Now your branch is based on master.

See [the docs for git-rebase](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase), specifically the --onto section.

Comment: But if `develop` is ahead of `master`, will this carry those commits too?

Comment: No, I added a link to the docs, your exact example is in there when they discuss --onto.